# Query run with Python doesn't perform unixtime function in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, database, unix-timestamp

i am new to Python (second day of programming with it).I am connecting with a MySQL database and performing a simple query. The query is retrieved from an SQL file in the package directory.

SQL Query (test.sql):

```
SELECT
    `lastUpdated`,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(`lastUpdated`/1000) AS lastUpdated2
FROM database.table
```

Python Code:

```
#Connect to MySQL
db_src = MySQLdb.connect(host="host", user="user", passwd="pass", db="db")
cursor = db_src.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

def getData():
    script_file = open(os.path.abspath("SQL/test"),"r")
    script = script_file.read()

    cursor.execute(script)
    script_file.close()

    data = cursor.fetchall()

    count = 0

    for row in data:
        count += 1
        print (count.__str__()),
        for attr in cursor.description:
            print unicode(row[attr[0]]),

        print ""

getData()
```

The output does not return my unix timestamps as DateTimes (which is the expected output if run from SQL-Yog). In place of these values, I am getting the word 'None'.

Output:

```
37 1358842638006 None 
38 1358846200484 None 
39 1358848721741 None 
40 1358859525442 None 
41 1358931853983 None 
42 1359015289550 None 
43 1359378691868 None 
44 1359558816786 None 
45 1359641991480 None 
46 1359642003819 None 
47 1359642020226 None 
48 1359729663885 None 
49 1359731426736 None 
50 1359732074609 None 
51 1359956455460 None 
52 1359987432110 None 
53 1360055172005 None 
54 1360137976835 None 
55 1360212322371 None 
56 1374050402290 None 
57 1375887780000 None 
58 1381830309000 None 
59 1382034299000 None 
60 1382613529000 None
```

Any ideas why FROM_UNIXTIME is not working?

EDIT: SOLUTION

Python dynamically casts the result of FROM_UNIXTIME in the wrong data type. I therefore use a cast in the query to output a char result which is cast as a string succesfully by Python.

```
SELECT
  lastUpdated,
  CAST((FROM_UNIXTIME(lastUpdated/1000)) AS CHAR) AS lastUpdated2
FROM database.table
```

Answer (score 0):

`88867351610262145/1000` is `88867351610262.1450` which would correspond to `Mon Apr  7 07:17:42 UTC 2818064` - that's out of the range of MySQLs datetime type, so `from_unixtime` returns Null.

Comment: Maybe it's in nanoseconds, not in milliseconds? `from_unixtime(88867351610262145/10e9)` is `1970-04-13 21:32:15`. That could make more sense...

Comment: Actually scratch that, there was a typo in the question. I'm going to make an edit.

Comment: It's not the range of the value I think.. Running this from SQLyog works normally. I copy pasted the query but its not resolving the unixtime into datetime.

Comment: Can someone try to replicate it quickly with a table? Shouldn't take too long. I've also noticed that other functions like CONCAT work ok.